# how to get json title

Tags: java, javascript, json

I am having issue with getting title of the schema element in JSON form,  so far I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function() {
        $("#thisForm2").validationEngine('attach', {
          onValidationComplete: function(form, status) {
            if (status === true) {
              return true;
            }
          },
        });
        $("#thisForm2").validationEngine({showArrowOnRadioAndCheckbox: true});
      });
      $(function() {


        $('form#thisForm2').jsonForm(
{
          "schema": {
            "adminName": {
              "type": "string",
              "title": "Admin Name"
            },
            "adminEmail": {
              "type": "string",
              "title": "Admin Primary E-mail"
            },
            "size": {
              "type": "array",
              "title": "Size",
              "enum": ["1-100", "100-1K", "1K-10K", "10K+"],
            },
          },
          "form": [
            {
             "key": "adminName",
             "fieldHtmlClass": "form-control validate[minSize[2]]",
            },
            {
             "key": "adminEmail",
             "fieldHtmlClass": "form-control validate[minSize[2]]",
            },
            {
              "key": "size",
              "fieldHtmlClass": "form-control dropDownPrepend validate[minSize[2]]"
            },
          ]
        });

      });
    </script>
```

In backend, when I use `Map<String, String> allRequestParams`, I am able to get key/value pair for JSON form, like `{adminName=Godzilla, adminEmail=abc@abc.com, size=1K-10K}`

So the question is: "How do I get title of the element in back-end?" By title I mean this:

```
"title": "Admin Name"
```

Tried to copy title from schema part to form part of JSON, but it seems not working. Maybe I can do some javascript and parse it? I am new to JSON so I might not know obvious things, any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like using Jquery, can try something like this,

```
var titles = [];
$.each(schema[0].adminName, function(index, item){
   titles.push(item.title);
})
```